# animated Geometric effect like ie logo

Tags: jquery, css, effect, geometric-arc

I want animated Geometric effect like ie logo (yellow color) which moves around my logo. 
[image: yellow line effect]

Comment: i don't know what did you mean by effect like ie logo , this is made by adobe illustrator or photoshop , if you want an effect like this with jquery or html5 and css3 i suggest you to do it with the SVG PATH , this can draw geometric form and curve lines and soo many things ...

Comment: not exact but almost using css3. http://cordobo.com/wp-content/uploads/ie-pure-css-logo/

Comment: yes.. I want geometric effect on my logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted something like **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5jbop4Lc/1/)**

```
<div class="logo">
<div class="circle"></div>
<img src="http://cdns2.freepik.com/image/th/318-31882.png" />
</div>

*{
box-sizing:border-box;
}
.logo{
width:150px;
height:150px;
position:relative;
}
.circle{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:100%;
border:10px solid #000;
border-radius:100%;
}
.logo img{
width:70px;
display:inline-block;
position:absolute;
top:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
left:0;
margin:auto;
vertical-align:middle;
}  
.circle {
-moz-animation: rotate 10s infinite 0s;
-webkit-animation: rotate 10s infinite 0s;
animation: rotate 10s infinite 0s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate{
0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(50,50,0,50deg) rotate(90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(50,50,0,50deg) rotate(90deg);    
    transform: rotate3d(50,50,0,50deg) rotate(90deg);
}
50% {
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg) rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg) rotate(180deg);    
    transform: rotate3d(0,0,0,0deg) rotate(180deg);
}
100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate3d(-50,-50,0,-50deg) rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(-50,-50,0,-50deg) rotate(-90deg);    
    transform: rotate3d(-50,-50,0,-50deg) rotate(-90deg);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think Jquery would be what you need, do you mean actually building that shape so its rendered by the browser rather than through an image? You might be able to get *something* like it through CSS. It probably wont be exactly right though.

There are a few examples of CSS shapes you can build here:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

But yeah the best bet would be to just make the image using an image editor and put it online as an image.